# JPA join by one value or another

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an example database as a simplification of a real life production environment. In this case, there's a student table (id, name, **teacher**) and a teacher table (id, name, badge_code). The teacher can be identified by their badge_code or by name, and there is a many-to-one relationship between these two tables, where a teacher corresponds to many students.

The thing is that the student table has its **teacher** column, and this column may have either the teacher's name or badge code. If I want to successfully join these tables, a query like this would be enough:

```sql
select * from student s
left join teacher t on s.teacher = t.badge_code or s.teacher = t.name
```

If the first join condition fails, it falls back to the second possible match. This is a left join, so it can be null cases.

I want to replicate this join in JPA and I don't know how to do it. It doesn't matter if it's by annotations, JPQL or a criteria query; any option will be fine. I know this kind of reference is not ideal between tables, but unfortunately, I'm unable to change how data is related in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using @JoinFormula annotation from Hibernate, so my student entity looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(select t.id from teacher t where t.badge_code = teacher or t.name = teacher)")
    private Teacher teacher;

...
```

It looks like a native SQL query between parentheses **that returns the target entity id**, is enough to join given two or more conditions with the same column, like in this case.